# Install a given version of MongoDB with Chef Solo and Vagrant

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm playng with Vagrant and Chef Solo for educational purpose. I would raise up an Ubuntu machine with a given version of MongoDB (in the next future I would share the machine with my colleagues to make development machines, so it necessary that we all run the same environment).
This is my Vagrantfile, it works and using [this MongoDB recipe](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mongodb) (and all related dependecies):

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "mongodb"

    chef.json = {
      "mongodb" => {
        "package_version" => "2.6.4"
      }
    }
  end

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017
end
```

After `vagrant up` the results is impredictable since the version installed don't reflect `package_version`. Where is the mistake? Can I specify version to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it tries to install the mongo deb package provided in the ubuntu repo. You specified a version to install that is not present in this repo:

```
==> default: STDERR: E: Version '2.6.4' for 'mongodb' was not found
```

If you want to install an alternative version that is different to the ubuntu provided version, you would need to add in the mongodb-org repo. You can do this by adding the following recipe:

```
chef.add_recipe "mongodb::mongodb_org_repo"
```

So your Vagrantfile now looks like:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "mongodb::mongodb_org_repo"
    chef.add_recipe "mongodb"
    chef.json = {
      "mongodb" => {
        "package_version" => "2.6.4"
      }
    }
  end

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017
end
```

You can confirm the version of the mongodb-org package installed by:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ dpkg -l | grep mongodb-org
ii  mongodb-org                              2.6.4                      MongoDB open source document-oriented database system (metapackage)
ii  mongodb-org-mongos                       2.6.11                     MongoDB sharded cluster query router
ii  mongodb-org-server                       2.6.11                     MongoDB database server
ii  mongodb-org-shell                        2.6.11                     MongoDB shell client
ii  mongodb-org-tools                        2.6.11                     MongoDB tools
```